# How to copy all content of a folder excluding one filetype?

Tags: file-transfer, alias

I have a folder containing 74 subfolders, that has a number of aliases strewn about within it.  I'm trying to copy the entire top-level folder (and all of its contents, obviously) over to Google File Stream, but GFS cannot store a mac alias.  The Finder copy will fail if there is an alias within the file set being copied.

How can I copy the top level folder and everything contained within, maintaining all structure, but skipping over aliases?  I'm guessing this would require some sort of terminal command.  GFS appears just as a normal network volume to the Mac so, I think there should be a way.